# Does Flame Spiral's Effect damage change elements from Lightning/Frost Weapon?

Tags: dnd-4e, sorcerer

Flame Spiral's effect line says

> Until the start of your next turn, any enemy that enters a square adjacent to you or starts its turn there takes 1d6 fire damage. An enemy can take this damage only once per turn.

while Lightning/Frost Weapon has as its at-will power

> All damage dealt by this weapon is (cold/lightning) damage. Another free action returns the damage to normal.

So would Flame Spiral's effect damage count as "damage dealt by this weapon", if cast though a Lightning/Frost Dagger or Staff?

Answer (score 3):

#### Yes, Flame Spiral's effect damage type can be changed by weapons.

Damage dealt by Flame Spiral's effect is dealt by Flame Spiral. Flame Spiral has the Implement keyword, therefore damage dealt by Flame Spiral is dealt by the implement used to cast it, even if the implement is also a weapon.